# Is cin.get() reading multiple digit characters at once?

Tags: c++, io

We were asked to write a simple C++ program by our teacher to add two numbers in the following format:

```
input: 12 14
output: m+n = 26
```

The program must also work for other inputs in the form:

```
input: Hello please add 12 and 14 !
output: m+n = 26
```

The solution that was given was:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int m,n;
char ch;
while(cin.get(ch)){
if(isdigit(ch))
{
cin.putback(ch);
cin>>m;
break;
}
}
//cin.putback() restores the last character 

//read by cin.get() back to the input stream
while(cin.get(ch)){
if(isdigit(ch))
{
cin.putback(ch);
cin>>n;
break;
}
}
cin.ignore(80,'\n');
cout<<"m + n = "<<m+n<<endl;
return 0;}
```

But now I need to know why this program also works for numbers that are not single digits. Shouldn't cin.get(char) just read one digit and cin.putback() return the same? Please help me I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `cin.get()` will read only one character at a time.

The important part, where the number is actually read, is 4 lines below: `cin>>m;`. This will consume as many digits as possible and store the resulting integer in `m`.

Some more details:

```
// example with input 524 42

while(cin.get(ch))        // extract one character at a time
{                         // ch='5', remaining input="24 42"
    if(isdigit(ch))       // if it's a digit (0-9), then:
    {                         
        cin.putback(ch);  // Put it back into the stream, "unread" it
                          // remaining input="524 42"
        cin >> m;         // extract an integer from stream
                          // m=524, remaining input="42"    
        break;
    }
}
```

---

The reason for the loops seems to be to skip over any non-numeric input before a number appears. Note that there is a little bug here, since it will also ignore leading signs. (e.g. input `-4 4` will output `m + n = 8`)

Comment: Thank you!   I tried reading the same data with a char m instead of an int m and found that all the digits (till a non digit character) is read into the int m variable but only the first character is read into the char m variable. I guess it happens due to the datatype.   Ill try to fix the bug that you mentioned.